# Addition of new node in Cassandra ring without changing the token of the ring

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I am using `Cassandra 3.9` on production and i wanted to add one more node in the ring. So, is there a way of adding new node in the ring without modifying the tokens for the rest of the ring? 
FYI, I am using RandomPartitioner in my ring and not using vnodes

Comment: Isn't that given by default? Consistent hashing is all about keeping that requirement http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeHashing_c.html

Comment: @BartoszBilicki I am using `random partitioner`. So for that you need to define the token.  http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.in/2015/07/cassandra-data-partitioning-using.html

Comment: Why tag for Cassandra 2.0 / 2.1 if you're using 3.9?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when adding a node in a single token cluster you will subsequently perform a `nodetool move` to shift existing nodes to new tokens otherwise you would have an imbalance in token ownership.

However, token movement can be resource intensive. Consider what your end goal is. If you were eventually going to double the size of your cluster, you could calculate tokens for twice the number of existing nodes. Then you will get token values for halfway points and you can add the new nodes in at those new tokens. Your existing nodes therefore would not need to move token ownership.

This is only if your end goal is to double the size of the cluster.